# Pure css input group border issue

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I'm using PureCSS and have a form that looks like:

```
<form class="pure-form">
   <fieldset class="pure-group">
       <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Username">
       <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="About me bio"></textarea>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="pure-group">
       <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Another Group">
       <input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="More Stuff">
   </fieldset>

   <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkuex/).

Basically my issue is that with the two input group, the borders on focus show around the entire input, but with the one input and one textarea group, the borders on focus don't show on top of the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the textarea on focus. In addition, if you take the `top:-2px` off, you won't get a jump when you focus on it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V82yd/1/)

**CSS**

```
.pure-form .pure-group input:last-child,
.pure-form .pure-group textarea:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
textarea:focus{
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding :
    margin-top: 1px;

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the CSS for the first input field in you example you'll see:

```
pure-form .pure-group input:first-child {
    top: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

The `top: 1px` is pushing the input field down one pixel and covering the text-area field below it. You could remove the `top: 1px` rule from the CSS or add a `margin-top: 1px` rule to the `.pure-form .pure-group textarea:last-child` class.